# How can I get links that match a regex using WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I'm trying to use regular expressions to catch a link, but can not.
I have all the links, but there are many links that do not want.

What I do is to grab all links:
`http://valeptr.com/scripts/runner.php?IM=`
To comply with this pattern.

I put the script I'm doing:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use WWW::Mechanize::Sleepy;

my $Explorador =

    WWW::Mechanize->new(

       agent =>
             'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624',

       sleep => '5..20'
    );

#Proceed to access the URL to find all the links in emails
$Explorador->get("file:/home/alejandro/Escritorio/hehe.php.html");

#If you want debug DOM Document.
#print $Explorador->content();

my @links = $Explorador->links;

foreach my $link (@links) {

   # Retrieve the link URL like:
   # http://valeptr.com/scripts/runner.php?IM=0cdb7d48110375.
   my $href = $link->url;

   foreach my $s ($href) { #Aqui la expresión regular

       my @links = $s =~ qr{
                               (
                               [^B]*
                               )
                               $
                           }x;
       foreach (@links) {
           print "\n",$_;
       }
   }
}
```

PS: I guess this regular expression will be more than seen but not seen. If so am coming back to put a post with the same.

Problem:
 There is a heap of links and I need cojer the links that expire with the boss:
 `Http: // valeptr.com/scripts/runner.php?IM=`
 For it in the line 19 I have to apply an expression regulate.
 This variable my @links=$Explorador->links; he returns all the links that exist.
 But I want cojer only the link that I have put above.
Sincerely,

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more clear on what exactly you need.

Comment: Post your code here. Put some effort into properly formatting it.

Comment: ok I put my code in post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not get `WWW::Mechanize` to do the work for you, especially when it can filter out the links for you via a supplied regex?

```
my @wanted_links = $Explorador->find_all_links ( 
                                     url_regex => qr{scripts/runner\.php\?IM=}
                                );
```

No `for` loops!

Answer (score 0):

As your reference link seems to be fix, you could take into account using substr instead of regex

```
$ref_link = q!http://valeptr.com/scripts/runner.php?IM=!;
foreach my $link ( $Explorador->links ) {
    my $href = $link->url;
    if ( substr($href, 0, length($ref_link)) eq $ref_link ) {
        push @save, $href;
    }
}
```